# Extract last number from text string

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have the following text in cells `A1:A13`. I would like to extract the last number from the string. As you can see, some strings contain several numbers, some with leading zeros, some with a slash space, others with only a slash, some ending with text others not.

I would prefer to do this with a formula, instead of using a VBA script.

```
MC HOPE /0217
MC HOUSTON (BTL-020) / 2737
MC HWY 69 S. [ALLTEL] /5910
MC I-475 & HAMILTON / 0380 [EBH]
MC I496 EAST / 0415 [ON-NET FIBER - EBH]
MC I675 / 0267
MC I-675 HERZNER [ALLTEL] /0249
MC I-69 & BROADWAY [ALLTEL] /5404
MC I69 & DORT HWY / 0309 [EBH]
MC I69 & GRAND TRAVERSE / 0384 [EBH]
MC I69 & I94 / 2472
MC I69 & I94 II [ALLTEL] /5847
MC I69 & M15 / 0327
```

Should come up with:

```
217
2737
5910
380
415
267
249
5404
309
384
2472
5847
327
```

*Edit not from OP*

per comment: "Some items have more than one slash."

Comment: Are square brackets the only thing that can appear after the numbers?

Comment: Yes, but they are not there in every case.

Comment: Formulas are math, not scripts.  What you want done is exactly what VBA is for.

Comment: @TravisO OP is looking for non-vba solution so i think vba tag is not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the the numbers are the only thing that can appear immediately after a number and you have an indeterminate number of digits in the number, you can use this formula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("/",A1)+1,IFERROR(FIND("[",A1,FIND("/",A1))-FIND("/",A1)-1,LEN(A1)))*1
```

[image]

EDIT: For multiple forward slashes, you can try this 'monster' formula:

```
=MID(A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))))+1,IFERROR(FIND("[",A2,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","")))))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",""))))-1,LEN(A2)))*1
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's happening in the IFERROR portion of your formula?  It has me intrigued.

Comment: Seems to work, but what if there are more than one slash?   ie. MC LIVERNOIS & 6 1/2 MILE/0959 [EBH]

Comment: @ChrisYoung If there are more than a single slash, then the formula will become longer, unless you are okay with a helper column.

Comment: @Jerry - formula length is not an issue, would prefer that over helper columns. I'm using Excel 2010

Comment: @ChrisYoung I updated my answer. The last formula deals with multiple forward slashes. I used `CHAR(1)` because I don't think you'll have that in your strings.

Comment: @Jerry - WOW, that is a monster, but it works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: @ChrisYoung You're welcome ^^ A helper column would've cut the length by about a half or so.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a more efficient formula, but building on Santosh's solution this formula converts the number to hex and back to decimal, there by removing the leading zero.

```
=HEX2DEC(DEC2HEX(MID(A1,SEARCH("/",A1)+1,5),4))
```

**EDIT to address multiple slashes:**

Solution #1

```
=HEX2DEC(DEC2HEX(MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))+1,5),4))
```

Solution #2

As pointed out by pnuts `*1` can replace the HEX2DEC and DEC2HEX to shorten the formula.

```
MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))+1,5)*1
```

Comment: Hmm, Perhaps there is a misunderstanding.  I'm trying to extract the last set of digits from the string.  Perhaps this answer was meant for another question?

Comment: Yes, for the following string, I get 5924 instead of 89 - MC LIVONIA MALL/0089 [EBH] and I should get 808 for MC LIVERNOIS & DIX / 0808 [EBH] but using your formula I get 1080.... oh perhaps I am the one that misunderstood.. You are building on Santosh's reply.. I thought you were offering your own..  if the future maybe add your answer as a comment to his.. maybe that would be more clear.   I'm currently unable to change my downvote sorry.

Comment: Chris, this answer is tested against the examples given in your question and confirmed to work in Excel 2007.  Your comment examples also are confirmed to work with the above formula.  Note, this answer does not address multiple slashes, but that wasn't noted in the original question.  I've updated my solution to corresponding with Santosh's update.  @pnuts Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @pnuts It was my first thought because I've worked with those two formulas extensively in the past, where I had to convert from hex to decimal, do some math, then convert back to hex.  As far as using *1, there you have it!  As noted in my answer as a possibility, a more efficient formula.  :)

Comment: @pnuts, I added your `*1` comment to the solution with an observed difference in the results.

Comment: @pnuts I must have brought the align over from something else I was doing.  Both solution 1 and 2 had `general` formatting, but then I started a new sheet, I couldn't observe the difference after all.  I've removed the comparison from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know you want to avoid VBA but for for completeness I've added a solution.

The advantage is that you can use `Regex` which is extremely good for tasks like yours. It worked based on your data set provided.

```vb
Sub GetLastDigits()
    Dim Entries As Range, entry As Range
    Dim RegEx As Object, Matches As Object, Match As Object

    Set Entries = Range("A1:A12") //Set this as per your s/sheet set-up
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With RegEx
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(\d+)" //Match any set of digits
    End With

    For Each entry In Entries
        Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(entry)
        If VBA.Left(Matches(Matches.Count - 1), 1) = 0 Then
            entry.Offset(0, 1) = VBA.Right(Matches(Matches.Count - 1), Len(Matches(Matches.Count - 1)) - 1)
        Else
            entry.Offset(0, 1) = Matches(Matches.Count - 1)
        End If
    Next entry
End Sub
```

Comment: @brettdj - and thanks to you as I've used http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=68 that I think you've posted online for download that shows how to use regex in VBA. I learned a lot from that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula for B1 `=MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))+1,5)` . Drag it till the end. Then you can manully format the result column to remove the leading zero.

[image]

Comment: Some items have more than one slash. should have included that in the example.  ie. MC LIVERNOIS & 6 1/2 MILE/0959 [EBH]

Comment: @ChrisYoung Try this formula `=MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))+1,5)`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try (put in B1):

`=1*LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),99)),4)`